# Nesting a http request inside list of promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

I have a service *function* that returns a list of promises:

```
getData(user) {
     return this.$q.all({
        userInfo: this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.getinfo', user)),
        userTopArtists: this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.gettopartists', user)),
        userChart: this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.getWeeklyChartList', user))
    }).then(resp => {
        return resp;
    }).catch(err => {
        this.$q.reject('Error' + err.status);
    })
}
```

, which I'm calling inside my controller:

```
validateUser() {
     this.error = null;
     this.service.getData(this.$scope.username)
        .then(resp => {
            if (resp.userInfo.data.user) {
                this.service.storeUserData('userData', JSON.stringify(resp));
                this.$location.path('/profile');
            } else {
                this.error = resp.userInfo.data.message;
            }
        })
}
```

Works fine until now but what I'm looking for is manipulating what data I get from the `userChart` request in particular.

I want to manipulate the json I get from calling `userChart`, store some of it inside of an array and make another request that returns data using the stored array object values from the initial request as parameters.

So basically I don't need the json from `userChart`, I just need to use to it make a nested(?) request using some of its data.

Comment: add `then` to your `userChart` definition and return another promise from inside that `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return a promise from the `then` the caller of the original promise will wait until the nested promise is resolved. It does not matter if the caller was your service using `$q.all` or something else, it is chained.

This shows just the relevant code, it located in your service with everything else being unchanged.

```
userChart: this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.getWeeklyChartList', user))
    .then((result) => {
       // additional manipulation if needed on result
       // second call to http and return the resulting promise
       return this.$http.doSomething('');
    });
```

Comment: Excellent, my mistake was not returning the result in the nested promise.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but maybe you could do something with the result of that call as soon as it comes back?  Something like this?

```
getData(user) {
     return this.$q.all({
        userInfo: this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.getinfo', user)),
        userTopArtists: this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.gettopartists', user)),
        userChart: this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.getWeeklyChartList', user)).
          then(function(response) {
            // Do something with the successful response
          }, function(response) {
            // Do something for the failed response
          })
    }).then(resp => {
        return resp;
    }).catch(err => {
        this.$q.reject('Error' + err.status);
    })
}
```

Comment: Does it not call your success function or just doesn't execute at all?

Comment: It does call the succes function for that particular request, but ignores the other succes function for the $q.all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood yours needs you should first get the charts response and then use that response to call the other webservices, so something like this should work:

```
validateUser() {
    this.getData({})
        .then(function (response) {
            // response containing 'userInfo' and 'userTopArtists'
            console.log(arguments);
        });
}

getData(user) {
    const me = this;
    return me.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(function (charts) {
            return me.$q.all({
                // use charts as param for other calls...
                userInfo: me.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'),
                userTopArtists: me.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            me.$q.reject('Error' + err.status);
        });
}
```